# Difference between DBNull.Value and IsValueNull()

Tags: c#, linq, casting, dataset

I'm getting some data from Stored Procedure to DataSet and then copying that data to a List. There are some NULL values in data and for that I'm checking with DBNULL.Value. But whenever it comes to a NULL value, it gives me error

> ERROR : Specified cast is not valid.

This is how I'm copying data from DataSet to List.

```
AreaId = dsTable.SearchedTable[I]["AreaId"] == DBNULL.Value ? 0 : (long)dsTable.SearchedTable[I]["AreaId"];
```

Sometimes it works fine but sometimes it gives me error.

And when I change this **DBNULL.Value** to `IsAreaIdNull()`. It works fine.

```
AreaId = dsTable.SearchedTable[I].IsAreaIdNull() ? 0 : (long)dsTable.SearchedTable[I]["AreaId"];
```

I'm confused that what's wrong with **DBNull.Value** because it is working perfectly fine in other procedures. Even in same procedure for other values. M i missing something in it??

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's not `= DBNULL.Value` but `== DBNULL.Value`

Comment: yeah sorry it was a typo mistake. corrected

Comment: variable areaID can't be null. that's why i'm checking it while copying data

Comment: That's a strongly typed DataSet and not a losely typed DataSet. Use the second approach.

Comment: but what is wrong with first one?? it is working fine for other values.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a typo: assignment instead of equality comparison here:

```
dsTable.SearchedTable[I]["AreaId"] = DBNULL.Value ? 0 : 
                                                   (long)dsTable.SearchedTable[I]["AreaId"];
```

It should be

```
dsTable.SearchedTable[I]["AreaId"] == DBNULL.Value ? 0 : 
                                                    (long)dsTable.SearchedTable[I]["AreaId"];
```

Comment: yeahs it is ==. that was a typing mistake.